# Why is QueueClient crashing when talking to Azure Service Bus and is it safe to leave it potentially undisposed?

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, azure-worker-roles

I have the following situation:
I have Worker Role deployed on Azure which is used to read messages from Azure Service Bus. I also connected it with Application Insights service so I can track traces and exceptions. Very simplified algorithm in the worker role is:

```
while(true)
{
    queueClient = new QueueClient();
    try
    { 
        while(true)
        {
            queueClient.Receive();
        {
    }
    catch
    {
        queueClient.Dispose(); 
    }
}
```

Issue I get sometimes at some random time when no processing occurs is that QueClient Receive() method fails and throws the exception with the following trace:

```
Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessagingException:
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageReceiver.EndReceiveCommand (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageReceiver.OnEndTryReceive (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageReceiver+RetryReceiveAsyncResult+<>c.<GetAsyncSteps>b__15_3 (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageReceiver.OnTryReceive (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageReceiver.TryReceive (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageReceiver.TryReceive (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.QueueClient.Receive (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Novolyze.VOD.AzureServiceBusQueuing.ServiceBusQueue`1.Receive (Novolyze.VOD.AzureServiceBusQueuing, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullNovolyze.VOD.AzureServiceBusQueuing, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: D:\Development\Projects\Novolyze\Source\Novolyze.VOD.AzureServiceBusQueuing\ServiceBusQueue.csNovolyze.VOD.AzureServiceBusQueuing, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 67)
   at Novolyze.VOD.AzureServiceBusQueuing.ServiceBusQueue`1.Novolyze.VOD.ServiceBusQueuingInterface.IServiceBusQueue.Receive (Novolyze.VOD.AzureServiceBusQueuing, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullNovolyze.VOD.AzureServiceBusQueuing, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: D:\Development\Projects\Novolyze\Source\Novolyze.VOD.AzureServiceBusQueuing\ServiceBusQueue.csNovolyze.VOD.AzureServiceBusQueuing, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 118)
   at Novolyze.VOD.WorkerRoleWithSBQueue.WorkerRole+<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<OnStart>b__0 (Novolyze.VOD.WorkerRoleWithSBQueue, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullNovolyze.VOD.WorkerRoleWithSBQueue, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: D:\Development\Projects\Novolyze\Source\Novolyze.VOD.WorkerRoleWithSBQueue\WorkerRole.csNovolyze.VOD.WorkerRoleWithSBQueue, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 108)
Inner exception System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] handled at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageReceiver.EndReceiveCommand:
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.DuplexRequestBindingElement+DuplexRequestSessionChannel.ThrowIfFaultMessage (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.DuplexRequestBindingElement+DuplexRequestSessionChannel.HandleMessageReceived (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.DuplexRequestBindingElement+DuplexRequestSessionChannel.EndRequest (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement+ReconnectChannelFactory`1+RequestSessionChannel+RequestAsyncResult+<>c.<GetAsyncSteps>b__9_3 (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement+ReconnectChannelFactory`1+RequestSessionChannel.EndRequest (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.RedirectBindingElement+RedirectContainerChannelFactory`1+RedirectContainerSessionChannel+RequestAsyncResult+<>c__DisplayClass8_1.<GetAsyncSteps>b__4 (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.RedirectBindingElement+RedirectContainerChannelFactory`1+RedirectContainerSessionChannel.EndRequest (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement+ReconnectChannelFactory`1+RequestSessionChannel+RequestAsyncResult+<>c.<GetAsyncSteps>b__9_3 (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement+ReconnectChannelFactory`1+RequestSessionChannel.EndRequest (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageReceiver.EndReceiveCommand (Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
```

I catch the exception, write it to Application Insights and 20 secs after that Worker Role crashes. I found that another unhandled exception occurs which is the Timeout exception while trying to dispose QueueClient which happens after Receive() crashes. Here is the stack trace:

```
<Event xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event'><System><Provider Name='Windows Azure Runtime 2.7.0.0'/><EventID Qualifiers='49152'>2001</EventID><Level>2</Level><Task>1</Task><Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords><TimeCreated SystemTime='2018-08-23T00:53:36.988460700Z'/><EventRecordID>39</EventRecordID><Channel>Windows Azure</Channel><Computer>RD0003FF1F0254</Computer><Security/></System><EventData><Data>System.TimeoutException</Data><Data>Process ID: 2616
 Process Name: WaWorkerHost
 Thread ID: 13
 AppDomain Unhandled Exception for role Novolyze.VOD.WorkerRoleWithSBQueue_IN_0
 Exception: The operation did not complete within the allotted timeout of 00:00:20. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout. For more information on exception types and proper exception handling, please refer to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=761101
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageReceiver.OnEndClose(IAsyncResult result)
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.ClientEntity.EndClose(IAsyncResult result)
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.CloseEntityCollectionAsyncResult.CompleteClose(ClientEntity entity, IAsyncResult result)
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageClientEntityManager.EndClose(IAsyncResult result)
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpQueueClient.CloseAsyncResult.&lt;&gt;c.&lt;GetAsyncSteps&gt;b__3_3(CloseAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpQueueClient.OnEndClose(IAsyncResult result)
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.ClientEntity.EndClose(IAsyncResult result)
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.ClientEntity.Close(TimeSpan timeout)
 at Novolyze.VOD.AzureServiceBusQueuing.ServiceBusQueue`1.Dispose(Boolean disposing) in D:\Development\Projects\Novolyze\Source\Novolyze.VOD.AzureServiceBusQueuing\ServiceBusQueue.cs:line 98
 at Novolyze.VOD.WorkerRoleWithSBQueue.WorkerRole.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass7_0.&lt;OnStart&gt;b__0() in D:\Development\Projects\Novolyze\Source\Novolyze.VOD.WorkerRoleWithSBQueue\WorkerRole.cs:line 142
 at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
 at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
 at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
 at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

 Inner Exception: The operation did not complete within the allotted timeout of 00:00:20. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout. For more information on exception types and proper exception handling, please refer to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=761101
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.DuplexRequestBindingElement.DuplexRequestSessionChannel.ThrowIfFaultMessage(Message wcfMessage)
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.DuplexRequestBindingElement.DuplexRequestSessionChannel.HandleMessageReceived(IAsyncResult result)
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.DuplexRequestBindingElement.DuplexRequestSessionChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result)
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory`1.RequestSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult.&lt;&gt;c.&lt;GetAsyncSteps&gt;b__9_3(RequestAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory`1.RequestSessionChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result)
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.RedirectBindingElement.RedirectContainerChannelFactory`1.RedirectContainerSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass8_1.&lt;GetAsyncSteps&gt;b__4(RequestAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.RedirectBindingElement.RedirectContainerChannelFactory`1.RedirectContainerSessionChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result)
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory`1.RequestSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult.&lt;&gt;c.&lt;GetAsyncSteps&gt;b__9_3(RequestAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory`1.RequestSessionChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result)
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageReceiver.AbandonPrefetchedMessagesCloseAbortAsyncResult.&lt;&gt;c.&lt;GetAsyncSteps&gt;b__2_3(AbandonPrefetchedMessagesCloseAbortAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageReceiver.OnEndClose(IAsyncResult result)

 </Data></EventData></Event>
```

Since I don't have paid support plan for asking technical questions engineers from Azure, does anyone have an idea:

1. Why those exceptions occur (maybe Service bus instance is unhealthy or it is something in my code that I am missing)?
2. If I wrap dispose in try catch, and suppress the exception about disposing failure, can I be sure that QueueClient will be garbage collected and that I will not make any troubles to just instantiate a new one?